# how can we find FFMPEG library file like any .so or .dll file

Tags: windows-10, window

i want  to code using java for a mp4 video compression so i needed a .so file or any MPEG library.
Or any sort of code using c++ for reference  or any video compression code .

Answer (score 3):

The FFMPEG libraries are called `libavcodec.so`, `libavformat.so`, etc. Here's the documentation:

- https://ffmpeg.org/libavcodec.html
- https://ffmpeg.org/libavformat.html
- https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Prebuilt libraries for Windows are available at https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds (select 'Shared' to get the .h and .dll files).

Note that MP4 is not a codec and does not compress video; it's a container (libavformat) that holds e.g. MPEG4 AVC (H.264) compressed video.

Comment: Specify some diffrences b/w Dev and shared. Those are different. Dev has static libraries and shared has dynamic ones.

Comment: Dev also includes C/C++ headers (.h) which AFAIK you'll need even if you're planning on linking against the shared/dynamic libraries.

Comment: The link to zeranoe.com is no longer valid.  https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases is an alternative.  Choose one of the 'shared' packages for development files.